# How to store and sort very big map?

Tags: java, hashmap, berkeley-db

I need to read large text file, parse each line and store parsed content in a map, with a String key mapped to objects I will create. For large maps, it seems it consumes memory quickly. I need to sort the map before it is output into a file; otherwise, I don't need to store all key-value pairs in memory.

I searched, and some suggested using map-reduce, and some suggested a database. In particular, it says Berkeley DB is a good choice. Is it straightforward to sort large key-pair values in Berkeley DB in Java and is it convenient to use it?

Comment: How large are we talking about?

Comment: The text file could be 10G, plus data structures to be created in the program. The total memory consumption could be 1000G above.

Comment: it do feel like you'd be better off delegating most of the data process to a DB indeed

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting

Comment: @SteveKuo, compared to "external sorting", sorting in DB may be simpler to implement?